# Test Suites for OpenStack Nova CLI

Tags: test-suite, openstack-nova

I am wondering if it is there any Test Suite for OpenStack Nova Command Line Interfaces.
I googled it and I found a bunch of Integration Test Suites (Tempest, Torpedo, StackTester, SmokeStack). Unfortunately, none of these Test Suite provides tests for Nova CLI.

Are you aware of any Nova CLI test suites?
I'd like to test sequences of commands like.

nova boot ...

nova list

nova image-list

Thanks

Comment: I have figured out that Tempest contains some basic CLI tests located at tempest/cli. Now I am trying to figured out out to run those tests.

Answer (score 0):

**Tempest**, is the framework you are probably looking for. There is a provision in tempest to run different kinds of testsuites like API,CLI etc.You can test the above mentioned commands using this CLI Testsuite